# ¿En que lugar de la aplicación coloco el interceptor de axios?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, axios

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion que en el frontend utilizo react.
mi intencion es que cuando la api rest devuelva como respuesta: error status 401 me redireccione a otra pagina y elimine el token:

Esta es la instancia para las peticiones:

```
let headers:Object = {};

let token = GetToken();
console.log(token);
if(token !== false){
headers = {
Authorization: `Bearer: ${token}`
};
}
const axiosIntance = Axios.create({
    baseURL:BASEURL,
    headers
})
export default axiosIntance;
```

Interceptor:

```
export function AxiosInterceptor(){
axiosIntance.interceptors.response.use(
    function(response){
        return response;
    }, function(error){
        if(error.response.status === 401){
            useHistory().push('/login');
        }else{
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
    }
)

}
```

Lo que desearia saber es donde colocar el interceptor ya que lo coloco en el app.js y no intercepta las respuestas

Answer (score 0):

Esa configuracion se ejecuta cada que hagas una peticion, debes de hacer el archivo donde coloques todas las configuraciones que quieres que realice axios en las peticiones.

Por ejemplo dentro de tu carpeta si estas trabajando con React se realiza lo siguiente:

- En la carpeta src colocar otra carpeta llamada Api/AxiosBase.js y en ella coloca la configuracion de axios.
- Lee la documentacion para que entiendas como funciona la estancia de axios, y ya que tenga el archivo con lo necesario solo lo importas y lo llamas con un try/catch y listo.

Espero te funcione.